# How to set a default app installer program?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an operating system that installs downloaded .apks from our servers. The issue I am having is that once downloaded I am prompted to select how I want to install the .apk. Among the options are Chrome, Browser and ESInstaller. I want to set ESInstaller as default programmatically. How can I do this?

Here is how I am calling the Intent to install the downloaded .apk.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(appUrl));
                startActivity(i);
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the packages your intent resolve to using [`Intent.setPackage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: I will try this out. I should pass the package I actually want right?